# Plot only producing straight line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to plot the function y = sec(x)/exp(tan(x)) however the code I used (which I've pasted below) only produces a straight line.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
   axis equal,axis lines=middle,
   width=12cm,height=7cm,
   xmin=-1.6,xmax=1.6,
   ymin=-1,ymax=2,
   yticklabel=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
   ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty]
\addplot[color=red,domain=-1.57:1.57,samples=100] {sec(x)/(exp(tan(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
```

I've tried individual functions. exp(x) worked, but tan(x) and sec(x) both similarly returned a straight line. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The trigonometric functions in `pgf` assume degrees as input, so you need `trig format plots=rad` in the `axis` options (or `trig format=rad`, which affects not only plots see the `pgfplots` manual), or convert to degrees with `deg(x)`, or use the `r` postfix as in Luis' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `sec` and `tan` are not being calculated in the correct way. Try something like `sec((x)r)` as in the following example (I changed the domain because `-1.5`to `1.5` gives numbers too big)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
   axis equal,axis lines=middle,
   width=12cm,height=7cm,
   xmin=-1.6,xmax=1.6,
   ymin=-1,ymax=2,
   yticklabel=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
   ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty]
\addplot[color=red,domain=-1.3:1.3,samples=100] {sec((x)r)/(exp(tan((x)r))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]